# removing text between CLOSEST delimiters in a string- regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex to get rid of strings between specific characters, for example "[" and "]":

```
input = "There is a [blue] cloud on top of that [big] elephant";
desiredOut = "There is a cloud on top of that elephant"; // this is what i want
```

But if I use regex to replace what is between "[" and "]" I remove everything between the first and last of this characters:

```
string input = "There is a [blue] cloud on top of that [big] elephant";
string regex = "(\\[.*\\])" ;
string actualOut = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");

actualOut = "There is a elephant" // this is what i get
```

Any clues on how to remove the stuff between inmediate delimiters? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This slight modification should solve your problem:

```
string regex = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
```

This bit `(.*?)` will match everything but will take as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "There is a (blue) cloud on top of that(big) elephant";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @" ?\(.*?\)", string.Empty);
```

this will do the job

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your regex removes everything between the first `[` and last `]` is because by default modifiers are greedy, ie. they match as many letters as possible.

You can use the lazy match as in the other answers, or you can use

```
string regex = @"\[[^\]]*\]"
```

This regex matches a left square bracket, then it takes anything *except* a right square bracket, and then finishes at the right square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

To remove also the leading or trailing space, you could use this

```
string actualOut = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\[[^\]]*\]\s+|\s+\[[^\]]*\]", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zW1yL4/1)